# How to make contributions to JSDT Template Proposals

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jsdt

I've created an eclipse plugin which extends JSDT. When editing a JavaScript file, pressing Ctrl-Space shows "Default Proposals", consisting of general JavaScript Suggestions. Pressing Ctrl-Space again shows "Template Proposals", but the list is empty. How do I add content to the "Template Proposals" list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `org.eclipse.ui.editors.templates` extension point for this.  Something like this:

```
<extension
    point="org.eclipse.ui.editors.templates">
 <template
       autoinsert="true"
       contextTypeId="javaScript"
       description="Do something"
       id="com.foo.mytemplate"
       name="A silly template">
    <pattern>
fafdsds fafdsda fdadsa
    </pattern>
 </template>
</extension>
```

Comment: Thats it, thanks! This works great for javascript files. However I'd also like to add some templates for css files. I tried changing the contextTypeId to CSS, to no avail. Any thoughts?

Comment: It looks like the ids you need to use are `css_all` or `css_new`.  Not very intuitive and the only way to find this out is by searching through the plugin.xml files.